# xen cluster multiple nodes

Tags: xen, cluster, high-availability

I'm looking for information on how to build a Xen HA cluster with multiple nodes. I find lots of information on how to build clusters with two nodes, but that is really not enough. I've built one with three nodes, but am unsure how to handle HA issues. Please provide links or write a howto right here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since been using [Openstack](http://www.openstack.org/)